# Trying to delete all elements of linked list but getting "ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address...."

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I was trying to solve Leetcode problem 24: "swapping nodes in Pairs" and tried to store all values of list to an array and then swap the elements of array and then create a new list while deleting old one. But doing so is resulting in this error :

```
> =================================================================
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x602000000058 at pc 0x0000003718bd bp 0x7ffebc26e360 sp 0x7ffebc26e358
READ of size 8 at 0x602000000058 thread T0
>  #2 0x7f90974760b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x602000000058 is located 8 bytes inside of 16-byte region [0x602000000050,0x602000000060)
freed by thread T0 here:
>    #3 0x7f90974760b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #4 0x7f90974760b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
>  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd[fd]fa fa fd fd
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fd fd fa fa fd fd fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fd fd fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 00
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa 00 00 fa fa fd fd fa fa fd fd fa fa fd fd
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fd fd fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
>  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==31==ABORTING
```

The code is :

```
 /**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* swapPairs(ListNode* head) {
        if(!head or !head->next)return head;
        
        vector<int> store;
        auto *p =head;
        while(p)
        {
            store.push_back(p->val);
            p=p->next;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<store.size()-1;i+=2)
        {
            swap(store[i],store[i+1]);
        }
        
        ListNode *newhead = nullptr; 
        for(int i=store.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            auto *temp = new ListNode(store[i],newhead);
            newhead=temp;
        }
        
        while(head)
        {
            auto *temp=head;
            head=head->next;
            delete temp;
        }

        return newhead;
    }
};
```

Could somebody please tell me what this error means and what I am supposed to do to delete the old list?
P.S. The error goes and code runs fine if I don't delete the old list.

Comment: *The error goes and code runs fine if I don't delete the old list.* -- The car runs fine if I remove the brakes.

Comment: Why do you need another vector to store the data?  Just go through the list in pairs.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing how you are actually using `swapPairs()`.

Comment: It seems unusual that _swapping elements of a linked list_ would require any `new` or `delete`.  I presume that the testing code expects any pointer to a `ListNode` to remain valid after they are rearranged.

Comment: Having deleted head, you don't change it to point to newhead. Maybe you do this in the code that calls swapPairs

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know that this is not the optimal approach and I have solved this problem without using additional space but I was just curious about what happens if I try to delete the original list and create new one? How fast the solution gets by using extra memory?

Comment: @sanyamjain -- Create a working linked list *class*.   If you did that, you would easily see what implications removing all elements and rebuilding the list are.

Comment: @Ian4264 After deleting the old list I tried pointing head to new head by `head=newhead`. I even tried deleting the old list first then create the entire list again by using head and not using newhead at all but both resulted in same error.